# I need to find all the files with .txt extension with their file size

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

something like du -hs *txt and find
30k avbd

I don't need their extension in output, just size and file name.

Comment: The extention is in the file name btw

Comment: And what did you try? What does `avbd` mean?!

Comment: Please notice that `du` shows the disk usage (in blocks) which is not the same as file size unless you add the option `-b` alias `--bytes`. A block is counted even if only a single byte or a few bytes of it is actually occupied by the file content.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in `du -hs *.txt`;do echo $f | sed 's/\(.*\)\.txt/\1/';done
```

The IFS part is necessary so that the for loop consumes the whole line at the same time.
Please also note the backticks around the "du -hs *.txt" part of the command. The backtick button should be above your tab button.

Answer (score 0):

### `ls`:

The easy solution for interactive use is "ell ess minus ell" where column #5 contains the file size in bytes

```
ls -l *.txt
```

or if you want 'human readable format'

```
ls -lh *.txt
```

You find more details in `man ls`. Please notice that `ls` is *not* recommended for automation (in shellscripts etc).

### `find`:

Your question was vague, so here is a list of commands to find and print text files with the extension `txt`. Pick the format you want or some combination. You find more details in `man find`.

The primitive list with only the names of text files in the current directory excluding for example directories and symbolic links but including files in subdirectories

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt"
```

A list with size (bytes) and file names

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%9s '%p'\n"
```

A list with sizes and names sorted according to size

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%9s '%p'\n" | sort -n
```

A list with sizes and names sorted according to name

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%9s '%p'\n" | sort -k2
```

A list excluding files in subdirectories with sizes and names sorted according to size

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%9s '%p'\n" | sort -n
```

The corresponding list where the dot and extension is removed from each file name

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%9s '%p'\n"|sed "s/\.txt'$/'/"|sort -n
```

The corresponding list where the name of the starting-point under which the file was found removed

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%9s '%P'\n"|sed "s/\.txt'$/'/"|sort -n
```